# Changing the default controller on start of program

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a new controller and view in my asp.net 5.0 mvc project and wanted that new controller to be the controller that is viewed on the very first start of the program instead of the default Home controller. The issue I am facing is that when I start the application it tells me

> invalidOperationException: The view 'UserIndex' was not found. The
> following locations were searched:
> /Views/UsernameEntry/UserIndex.cshtml /Views/Shared/UserIndex.cshtml

`UsernameEntryController`:

```
public class UsernameEntryController : Controller
{
    // GET: UsernameEntryController
    public ActionResult UserIndex()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

I then have a folder inside of views named UsernameEntry and the file name is UserIndex.cshtml

which contains `<h2>User entry testing</h2>`

I saw online that if I wanted to change the default controller on the start of the program I would need to make a modification in the Startup.cs file under the `Configure` method from this:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

to

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=UsernameEntry}/{action=UserIndex}/{id?}");
        });
```

but it did not work I even went to the properties of that `UserIndex.cshtml` and changed the build action from Content to Embedded resource but that still gave me the same message from above.

Comment: Your not routing to the correct location.

Comment: I am not? What should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup works just fine for me:

[image]

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=UsernameEntry}/{action=UserIndex}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

The `Build Action` of the view is set to its default value of `Content`.

Comment: Thank you! I deleted the folder again and re did the same steps and it worked. I think there a was a glitch or something because I had the same thing and it was not working